# www being forced before IP

Tags: nginx

I am assigned a access to a new server which uses Nginx as its webserver

Say, the ip is `344.555.122.45`

whenever I hit 344.555.122.45 in my browser it forces a www the IP
and it becomes `www.344.555.122.45`

Any idea what is causing it and how to fix this ?

Comment: Does that happen even if you explicitly say `http://344.555.122.45`? (I've known browsers to not understand IP addresses anymore, but that was Internet Explorer…)

Comment: Can you provide the current configuration of Nginx and obfuscate sensitive data?

Comment: it got nothing to do with server side...this is client side configuration and it is a pain in the ass. It happens with Safari (quite sure) and Chrome.Browsers default to add www when they cannot solve an entry. Either you use HTTP or there is a setting in Safari to disable search, which is another pain in the ass per se. You also are complaining about browser problems, however you did not tell us what browser you are using. Another alternative is creating a DNS name and stop using the IP address ;  I do advise  taking more time to write questions for future posts.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro not to mention the fact that if the server responds with a `301` permanent redirect status, the browser will literally always request the redirect, because - as the 301 status implies, the browser can always expect to get re-directed, so it will *never* hit the old URL even if you fix the server response, for this reason I always use chromes "disable cache when dev tools open" option. Also if the dev tools are open you can long press the reload button and chrome will give you more options to ignore cache etc

Comment: @the_velour_fog All granted, but I also have it here Safari changing accesses to IP addresses from my Internal network to www.IP_address

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways I can think of the redirect could be triggered

#### server side via HTTP

the server can cause this by sending a HTTP response that contains either `302` or `301` response status and a header `Location: http://www.344.555.122.45`.

The way I would test for this is with `curl -i 344.555.122.45`.
where the `-i` includes the header response. 
If you are getting this from the server, then I would look into the nginx virtual server config for the domain/host, if its not there, then I would look into the web application to see if thats setting the redirect.

#### in the HTML

There is also a way of doing this via the HTML code using a `<meta>` element, with the `http-equiv` attribute:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.344.555.122.45/" />
```

Although in my experience this is one of the least probable causes.

#### Your client side config is causing it

as mentioned in the comments

Comment: Alas, if it were a configuration...it is the default behaviour, and it is maddening even for experienced people. As a said in comments, you disable this, you also disable the search by default in the address bar. Maybe switching for a saner browser....